# Alternatives to Firebase Dynamic Links for Deep Linking

Tags: firebase, web, mobile, deep-linking, firebase-dynamic-links

I've been using Firebase Dynamic Links for deep linking in React JS, Next, Node project. However, I recently discovered that the Firebase Dynamic Links server is going to be shut down. As a result, I am in search of alternatives that can provide similar functionality, particularly the ability to display a preview with an image, description, and title for web & mobile.

Could you please suggest some best practices and decent alternatives for achieving deep linking functionality? I would greatly appreciate any insights or recommendations you can provide.

I have explored a few options. Some had only mobile functionality while I need both web & mobile. Some were paid tools that I couldn't check. As a result, I am still in search of a suitable alternative. I can try a paid one only in case I'm sure it meets my needs.

Answer (score 6):

AirBridge
Pros: Good tool, which has the same abilities as Firebase
Cons: SDK has not been covered by Unit Tests

BranchIO
Pros: Company has a migration guide. Github has a lot of Stars and pretty much every month releases.
Cons: nothing serious

AppsFlyer
Pros: Stable releases every one-two month
Cons: Has 20 open issues on GitHub